# Are there constituency parsers that do not aim for a full parse?

Tags: java, python, parsing, nlp, nltk

I am currently working on a set of report-styled documents, of which I want to extract information. At the moment, I am trying to divide the text body into smaller constituents, for individual classification (what kind of information do we expect in the phrase). Because of the inaccurate grammar in which the reports are written, a standard constituency parser won’t find a common root for the sentences. This obviously cries for dependency parsing. I was however interested whether there would be constituency parsers which do not aim for a full parse of the sentence. Something anlong the line of probabilistic CKY which tries to return most probable sub nodes. I am currently working in the Python nltk framework, but Java solutions would be fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for "shallow parsing", or "chunking". A chunker might just identify NPs in your text, or just NPs and VPs, etc.  I don't believe the nltk provides a ready to use one, but it's pretty easy to train your own. [Chapter 7](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#sec-chunking) of the nltk book provides detailed instructions for how to create or train various types of chunkers. The chunks can even be nested if you want a bit of hierarchical structure.